# How to display error message on php login without pop up box

Tags: php, authentication

I am looking to display an error message on the page when someone enters the incorrect username or password.  Right now it uses a popup box to display the message but I want it on the page itself.  How would I go about doing this? Below is my php

```
<?php
    if(!defined("SESSION")){
       session_start();
       define("SESSION", true);
 }
 if(isset($_GET["log_out"])){
    unset($_SESSION["logged_in"]);
    header('refresh: 0; url=login.php'); 
    exit;
 }

 $login = true;
 require "protect.php";

 $logins[0]["user"] = "";
 $logins[0]["pass"] = "";
 $logins[0]["redirect"] = "test.php";

 $logins[1]["user"] = "";
 $logins[1]["pass"] = "";
 $logins[1]["redirect"] = "";

 $logins[2]["user"] = "";
 $logins[2]["pass"] = "";
 $logins[2]["redirect"] = "test.php";

 // No need to edit below, except the errors

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //is the form submitted?
     if(empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['pass'])){
     header("Location: login.php");
     exit;
  } //check for empty user name or password
  $is_logged = false; //this is part of the process to see if they have a correct password or not, set to false right here to say no right pass... (will change later)
  foreach($logins as $login){
  $user = $_POST;
     if(($user["user"] == $login["user"]) && ($user["pass"] == $login["pass"])) {
   $is_logged = true;
   $_SESSION["logged_in"] = array($login["redirect"], true); //now, if they do have a correct password, set the session to true, and the variable.
  header("Location: ".$login["redirect"]);
  exit;
  }
 }
 if(!$is_logged){ echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Inncorect username or password");window.history.go(-1);</script>'; } //if none of the $logins arrays matched the input, give an error
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is use the echo command echo some html, instead of using Javascript.

Try this

```
echo '<p>Incorrect username or password</p>'
```

Comment: this works great but how would I display it under the form perhaps? This displays it at the top of the page

Comment: I suggest you go through some tutorials on the internet, or buy a book on how to use HTML and PHP. Experiment! Try and find out how to put it at the top of the page yourself, instead of trying to get other people to do all the work for you! 

Sure, ask for help when you need it - but there is so much information out there on how to do things like this already. You just need to look :).